# Facebook login using firebase in ios and swift, but cant get the users credentials

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate facebook login in my app (already have GOOGLE login set up), but in the `didCompleteWithResult` function when i call for the credential

```
let credential =  FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
```

i get an error : 
 `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

and every time i press my login button i have to enter my email address and password and before that i get another error : 
`2016-07-04 00:34:54.228 PrePathSigningIn[9693:438627] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2016-07-04 00:34:54.248 PrePathSigningIn[9693:438627] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"`

after i am done logging in my safari page does not take me back to my app page

my appdelegate file :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}



////////////////////////////////////////
//
//Google signin
//

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])


        return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication!,
            UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation]
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)

        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)


         return  handled
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        // ...


func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
        }



}
                                        //
         }
```

and my loginViewController :

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    print("RESULT : \(result)")
    print("ERROR : \(error)")

    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: {
    (user, error) in

        if error != nil{

            self.signInButton.enabled = true
            print("Problem at signing in with facebook with error : \(error)")
            self.showAlert("Error Signing in With Facebook", message: "Please enter the correct email and password")


        }else {
        print("USER LOGGED IN THROUGH FACEBOOK")
            _ = self.ref.child("users").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
                let usersDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]

                print(usersDict)
                if let userDetails = usersDict![user!.uid] as? [String : AnyObject], let _ = userDetails["username"] as? String
                {

                    let homePageScene = self.navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePageViewControllerVC_ID") as! HomePageViewController
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homePageScene, animated: true)

                }
                else{

                    let userNamePageScene = self.navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UsernameViewControllerVC_ID") as! UsernameViewController

                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userNamePageScene, animated: true)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I am a newbie...any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the providerData you now need something like this.

```
if let user = user {
} else {
print("User cancelled the Facebook login"))
}
```

You need to check if you have a user or if the user maybe canceled the login. Like this:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
for profile in user.providerData {
let providerId = profile.providerId
let uid = profile.uid;  // Provider-specific UID
let name = profile.displayName
let email = profile.email
let photoUrl = profile.photoURL
}
} else {
// No user logged in.
}



func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError?) {
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
}
```

Or some other additions:

```
let currentToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

// Show login if this is first time logging in
if (currentToken == nil || !currentToken.hasGranted("email")) {

    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com")
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
        (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            log.error("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i did it but it still give me an error can you explain to me what does `2016-07-04 00:34:54.228 PrePathSigningIn[9693:438627] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"` means?

Comment: This is an Xcode warning indicating that the `canOpenURL:` call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist you can ignore this warning. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9. It means the FB app is not installed on the device/simulator you're running on.